# Display items with different properties ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data

```
const menuItems = [
    { "id": "1", "category": "burger", "image": cranberryBurger, "title": "Cranberry", 
    "description": '100% Beef, Camembert, cranberry sauce, red onion, arugula, lamb`s lettuce', 
    "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "2", "category": "burger", "image": italianTaste, "title": "Italian taste", 
    "description": '100% Beef, mascarpone, black olives, dried tomatoes, red onion, arugula, iceberg lettuce', "price": '4$'},
    { "id": "3", "category": "burger", "image": mushroomBurger, "title": "Mushroom", 
    "description": '100% beef, mushrooms in sour cream, red onion, arugula, cheddar, iceberg lettuce', "price": '4$'},
    { "id": "4", "category": "burger", "image": seasonalBurger, "title": "Seasonal", 
    "description": '100% beef, tomato sauce, asparagus, red onion, iceberg lettuce, lamb`s lettuce', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "5", "category": "burger", "image": vegeBurger, "title": "Vege", 
    "description": 'Halloumi cheese, red onion, beetroot marinated in honey, homemade sauce, sunflower sprouts, lamb`s lettuce', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "6", "category": "crepe", "image": baconCrepe, "title": "Bacon", 
    "description": 'Mozzarella, grilled chicken, fried bacon, fresh tomatoes, BBQ sauce, spinach, arugula', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "7", "category": "crepe", "image": fourCheeseCrepe, "title": "4 cheese", 
    "description": 'Mozzarella, gorgonzola, camembert, parmesan, white sauce, arugula', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "8", "category": "crepe", "image": nutellaCrepe, "title": "Nutella", 
    "description": 'Nutella, Oreo bisquits, strawberries', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "9", "category": "crepe", "image": salmonCrepe, "title": "Salmon", 
    "description": 'Philadelphia cheese, fresh salmon, avocado, fresh cucumber', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "10", "category": "crepe", "image": vegeSalad, "title": "Vege salad", 
    "description": 'Beetroot marinated in honey, Halloumi cheese, pomegranate seeds, lamb`s lettuce, cashew nuts', "price": '5$'},
    { "id": "11", "category": "crepe", "image": coleslowSalad, "title": "Coleslow salad", 
    "description": 'Cabbage, lime juice, mayonnaise, lemongrass, coriander', "price": '5$'}
]
```

There is one property called `"category"` which has different value - either `"burger"` or `"crepe"`.
I want to pass `"category": "burger"` to one tab panel and `"category": "crepe"` to another tab panel.

```
<TabPanel>
        <div className="burgers">
          <ul> 
          {menuItems.map(menuItem => (
            <li key={menuItem.id}>
            <h4>{menuItem.title}</h4>
            <span>{menuItem.price}</span>
            <img src={menuItem.image} alt={menuItem.title} />
            <p>{menuItem.description}</p>
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(menuItem)}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
```

I tried to check if menu item category matches "burger"

```
{menuItems.map(menuItem => (
         if (menuItem.category === "burger") {
           return <li key={menuItem.id}>
            <h4>{menuItem.title}</h4>
            <span>{menuItem.price}</span>
            <img src={menuItem.image} alt={menuItem.title} />
            <p>{menuItem.description}</p>
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(menuItem)}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
}
            ))}
```

It's not working. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `.filter()`
2. use destructuring
3. add to cart only 'id' of product

```
  {menuItems
        .filter((v) => v.category === "burger")
        .map(({ id, title, price, image, title, description }) => {
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <h4>{title}</h4>
              <span>{price}</span>
              <img src={image} alt={title} />
              <p>{description}</p>
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(id)}>
                Add to cart
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: is it better than my attempt, maybe in good code practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the burgerCategory and crepeCategory and can map through it separately.

```
const categoryBurger = menuItems.filter((item) => item.category === "burger");

const categoryCrepe = menuItems.filter((item) => item.category === "crepe");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the ***format*** of the map function. After arrow there should be `{}`.

```
{menuItems.map(menuItem => {
    return (
    
    )
})}
```

Comment: thanks, actually yes, it was a mistake with formatting